# Assigning return to variable dosent work

Tags: maxima

I have an function which generate list with random numbers (with return statement). After I wanted to assign result of that function to variable.

something like that:

```
function() := (
     list:[5,2,5,3,60, 11, -5],
     return(list)
);

list2 : function();
```

but result of function dosent assign to list2. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maxima is not needed to add the retrun code to a function, it will return the last line, and also it is not necessary to assing the list a variable:

```
(%i19) my_function() := (
     [5,2,5,3,60, 11, -5]
);

list2 : my_function();
```

If you want to use return you can encapsulate  the code in a block:

```
(%i21) function() := (
     block(list:[5,2,5,3,60, 11, -5],
           return(list))
);
```

Then It should work, you have also the random function to generate random numbers:

```
makelist(random(10),10);
```

for example this generates a list with ten random integers from 0 to 9